# Force quit apps on shutdown automatically

Tags: mac, shutdown, applications

When I turn off my Mac if I have iTerm or FreeChat open, my Mac stops its shutdown and tells me that I need to manually quit these apps before shut down. I was wondering if there was a way to have it quit automatically for me when I shut down. I've looked at Mac Shutdown but its more of quitting at a certain time or event.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that it seems you're looking for a bandaid solution because the behaviour you describe is not _normal_. What I mean is that something is stopping the shutdown and you should really be trying to resolve _that_ issue, rather than implementing a workaround for the fact it's happening.

Comment: Also, have you got the latest versions of iTerm and FreeChat installed? Both of these are known to have had versions that cause issues for some users when shutting down. It may be worth also testing whether the behaviour still occurs when you've only got one of them open at shutdown.

Comment: I just downloaded FreeChat today so yes for that, not sure about iTerm. I'm not really sure if it's an issue. It's just when iTerm is running utop, Mac's shutdown just wants me to quit it before because a session is running, kinda like when Microsoft Word stops shutdown if you made edits to a document to ask if you want to save or not

Comment: However, I found terminal to not have this extra step of precuation so I have since switched from iTerm to terminal